# What is the right way to change a set of values on every row in a 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, broadcast

I have a 2D array 'A' with the shape (1015, 1200). Variable L1 has the lower indices and L2 has higher indices. On every one of the 1015 rows in A, I want to change the values of the elements between L1 and L2 pertaining to that row. I am using a for loop to carry this operation now and I want to know if there is any better way.

Here is the code that I am using now:

```
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    A[i, L1[i]:L2[i]] = 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mre] with all variables defined.

Comment: A[:, L1[i]:L2[i]] = 0?

Comment: For such a code, Numba or Cython are generally the way to go assuming this is a bottleneck in your application. There are tricks to speed this up regarding your exact use-case, but performance results are likely to be disappointing with Numpy.

Comment: It looks to me like you're code is working. What is the issue with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to slice numpy rows using start and end index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188161/how-to-slice-numpy-rows-using-start-and-end-index)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734116/numpy-how-to-slice-index-an-array-using-arrays

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could try if you want it to be vectorized is

```
x = np.arange(A.shape[1])
mask = (x >= L1[:, np.newaxis]) & (x < L2[:, np.newaxis])
A[mask] = 0
```

Although, I'm not sure if it'll be faster and it definitely uses a lot more memory.